# I lost audio and video (dummy ouput) when regressing from image header/kernel 5.4.0-47 to 5.4.0-26

Tags: drivers, sound, video, hdmi

I am running Linux 20.04 Linux Ubuntu currently with kernel 5.4.0-26-generic. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 a few months ago. My first problem was not having GPU detected after upgrading kernels... later no HDMI (this problem still persists) and currently both audio and video stopped working when I reverted kernel versions...

Below I describe my evolving situation and approximate steps taken so far.

My current system state as output by `inxi -SMA' is as follows:

```
>> inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: toro Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Precision 7510 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 086PC0 v: A03 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Dell v: 1.19.3 date: 10/04/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio driver: N/A 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM107 High Definition Audio [GeForce 940MX] driver: N/A
```

Evidently there are no audio drivers detected. This is also shown by `aplay -iL':

```
    aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

lspci commands `lspci | grep VGA && lspci | grep Audio`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               487424  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
binfmt_misc            24576  1
kvm_intel             286720  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
joydev                 24576  0
serio_raw              20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  2 uas
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
psmouse               155648  0
e1000e                258048  0
nvme                   49152  3
nvme_core             102400  5 nvme
i2c_i801               32768  0
ahci                   40960  1
rtsx_pci               69632  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  0
video                  49152  0
```

And hardware information as output by `sudo lshw -short -sanitize`:

```
H/W path               Device     Class          Description
============================================================
                                  system         Precision 7510 (06D9)
/0                                bus            086PC0
/0/0                              memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/43                             memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/44                             memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/45                             memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/46                             memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/47                             processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
/0/48                             memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/48/0                           memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/48/1                           memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/48/2                           memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/48/3                           memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/100                            bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                          bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                        display        GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
/0/100/1/0.1                      multimedia     GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX]
/0/100/2                          display        HD Graphics 530
/0/100/4                          generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                         bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0            usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/6                     communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/a                     generic        5880
/0/100/14/0/b                     multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/1            usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/5          scsi5      storage        My Passport 2627
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.0    /dev/sdb   disk           5TB My Passport 2627
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdb1  volume         4657GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.1               generic        SES Device
/0/100/14.2                       generic        100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/16                         communication  100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/17              scsi3      storage        Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
/0/100/17/0.0.0        /dev/sda   disk           2TB ST2000LM003 HN-M
/0/100/17/0.0.0/1      /dev/sda1  volume         1863GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1c                         bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c/0                       network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1c.2                       bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0                     generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.4                       bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1d                         bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0                       storage        XG4 NVMe SSD Controller
/0/100/1f                         bridge         CM236 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.2                       memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                       multimedia     100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.4                       bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
/0/100/1f.6            enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
...
```

Earlier I had issues with my Nvidia GPU card not being recognized. After extensive testing, I came to the realization, for some reason that I am still unclear about, kernels greater than 5.4.0-47 led to this result. Other than the GPU everything worked well.

Before I was working kernels 5.4.0-54. I decided to roll-back to 5.4.0-47 at first. I used sudo apt-get remove/purge on both the image header and the image kernel to do this. i.e.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-5.4.0-54*
sudo ap-get autoremove
```

Upon restart I was getting a blackscreen. Could still see kernel 5.4.0-54 in grub at start-up... I did a series of steps (which I cannot exactly list here) including `update-grub`.

That eventually led me to start-up correctly.

However, my audio did not work and kept showing 'dummy output'. I tried all of the usual steps with pulse-audio and alsa.

- killing pulseaudio (removing config files) and starting it up again.
- reinstalling/reloading alsa/rebooting
- alsamixer (installed): cannot open: no such file or directory.

The following website has a good summary of methods:
https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

All to no avail.

I am not very familiar with the following command `dnf install alsa-firmware`
But I cannot run it. I do not have dnf in Ubuntu nor can I find it with apt-get apt-cache search.

Also tried creating the pulseaudio service according to https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-make-pulseaudio-run-once-at-boot-for-all-your-users.

When running the `systemctl --system status pulseaudio.service` command, I get the following output:

```
● pulseaudio.service - PulseAudio system server
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit pulseaudio.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)


Nov 30 09:50:20 toro systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service:6: Unknown key name 'Exec' in section 'Service', ignoring.
Nov 30 09:50:20 toro systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Service has no ExecStart=, ExecStop=, or SuccessAction=. Refusing.
```

Any help on audio, video, hdmi is greatly appreciate.

Comment: It looks like you didn't install all kernel packages, like `linux-modules-extra`. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux`.

Comment: Today, wifi also was not working. I decided to do a reinstall... I won't know if that would have worked. Should I close this?